# AJAX call being handled but not rendering in rails view

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ajax

In a rails 4.2 application, a div lists and renders existing cartitems

```
  <div id='yield_cartitem'>
    <%= render 'cartitems' %>
  </div>
```

and the same page has forms (one per listed products).

```
<%= form_for(@cartitem, remote: true, id: 'data-js-cartitem-form', data: {'js-cartitem-form' => true}) do |f| %>

  <%= f.hidden_field :product_id, value: product.id %>
  <%= f.hidden_field :price, value: product.price %>
  <%= f.submit 'Add to cart' %>
<% end %>
```

The javascript for the class defines via jQuery

```
$(document).on('turbolinks:load', function() {
  $('[data-js-cartitem-form]').on("ajax:success", function(event, data, status, xhr){
    var cartitem = $(xhr.responseText).hide();
    $('#cartitems').append(cartitem);
    cartitem.fadeIn(1000);
    document.getElementById('data-js-cartitem-form').reset();
  });

  $('#cartitems').on("ajax:success", function(event, data, status, xhr){
    var cartitem_id = xhr.responseJSON.id;
    $('[data-js-cartitem-id=' + cartitem + ']').hide();
  });    
});
```

The controller create action runs as by design with the following rendering instruction.

```
  if @cartitem.save
    render partial: 'cartitem', locals: {cartitem: @cartitem}
  end
```

`_cartitems.html.erb` has

```
<div id=cartitems class='tableize'>
  <%= render partial: 'cartitem', collection: @cartitems %>
</div>
```

while `_cartitem.html.erb` defines

```
<div class='row' data-js-cartitem-id=<%= cartitem.id %>>
 <%= cartitem.quantity %>
 <%= cartitem.um %>
 <%= cartitem.product.try(:name) %>
 <%= cartitem.price %>
</div>
```

`_cartitem.js.erb` calls  `$("div#yield_cartitem").html('< %=j (render 'cartitem') %>');`

The XHR response payload is returning   `$("div#yield_cartitem").html('< %=j (render 'cartitem') %>');`  but the div is not refreshing with the newly created cartitem.

Where has this gone wrong?

**update**

Trying to simplify matters by changing the _cartitems.js.erb to an alert:

```
alert("<%= cartitem.quantity %> <%=j cartitem.um %> <%=j cartitem.product.try(:name) %> <%= number_to_currency(cartitem.price) %> Added")
```

The alert does effectively render.

`alert("1.0 kg Prod 1,89 € Added")`

Comment: Why don't you print the data in the javascript console and see if you are getting the data as expected?

Comment: I have.  Penultimate paragraph "The XHR response payload is returning $("div#yield_cartitem").html('< %=j (render 'cartitem') %>'); "   Now I have also tried an alert, see updated question.

Answer (score 1):

I may be wrong but I noticed that in controller you are passing locals to `cartitem` html partial but not in `js.erb` file. So do that in `cartitem.js.erb` file:

`$("div#yield_cartitem").html('< %=j (render 'cartitem', cartitem: cartitem) %>');`

it's really hard to debug `js.erb` files but it's possible. Try to use gem `pry` to see context and variables inside the partial.

```rb
$("div#yield_cartitem").html('<%= binding.pry; j(render 'cartitem', cartitem: cartitem) %>');
```

Answer (score 1):

`$("div#yield_cartitem").html('<%=j (render 'cartitem') %>')` this will replace the contents of `#yield_cartitem`

instead use `$('#cartitems').append('<%= j render('cartitem', cartitem: @cartitem) %>')`

and update this function

```
$('[data-js-cartitem-form]').on("ajax:success", function(event, data, status, xhr){
  // var cartitem = $(xhr.responseText).hide();
  // $('#cartitems').append(cartitem);
  // cartitem.fadeIn(1000);
  document.getElementById('data-js-cartitem-form').reset();
});
```

Additionally rename `_cartitem.js.erb` to `create.js.erb` then `create` will render it automatically